# dataSnapshot has the object but getValue() will return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm struggling with this issue for about three hours now. 
I have this user class

```
public class User {
private String user_id;
private String userName;
private long phoneNumber;

public User() {
}

public User(String user_id, String userName, long phoneNumber) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

And I want to fetch some instances of this class from Firebase Database I am using this code to do so:

 database reference;

```
User currentUser;
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
DatabaseReference usersRef = database.child("users");
```

query code:

```
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(user_id);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
}
```

Funny thing: this code actually worked once but I made some changes I guess, and now the getValue() returns null;

 this is my database in firebase

[image]
and when I debug the app the dataSnapshot actually contains the object I am looking for

[image]

but the currentUser will be an object with all its fields null;
[image]

any ideas? I'm getting really frustrated already :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your pictures are broken... Can you show us what the DataSnapshot class looks like?

Comment: @Aenadon sorry, i edited them, now they're ok any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to iterate over `dataSnapshot.getChildren(`...for example

```
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = childSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                 }
```

Comment: that worked! thanks, but can you explain why ? i already have a reference to the "users" node, why does it return the whole branch? or why do i have to get the children of that user node?  maybe i did not understand what dataSnapshot returns? can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: it's possible for queries like that that there can be multiple results.

Comment: i understand now, but i somehow thought that if you have a reference to a node and you search for an entry only that entry will be returned(or more if it is the case) but from what ia understand it will return the whole "users" node with the entries that satisfy the query

Comment: @kisslory because when you get first datashot is holds nodes(ids). And they return empty object for  User class matching. when you iterate them you get the objects enclosed in those nodes and they do match now. In my case the error was in mistyping .I called dataSnapshot instead of childesnapshot in the loop body.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem, turns out it was happening because the class (in your case User.class) doesnt have setter methods for the required variables

Comment: It is also possible to solve the problem making all required fields public. In my case they were package-private and I got null and zero values in fields. After making them public everything is set correctly.

Comment: @ValentinaKonyukhova thanks for this suggestion! I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code for the past hour, making it public fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

It can also return null if the read permission is set to false in firebase real-time database rules. Setting it to true would return the values.