# How to retrieve data from Firebase database, DataSnapShot returns null values and keys

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with implementing the Firebase realtime database to my application, the problem is that the DataSnapShot retrieves null keys and values.

I have tried looking at the documentation but I do not have a clue on what is wrong.

**Database structure:**

[image: Database Structure]

**My code:**

```
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

public NetworkRepository(){
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}

public void getFoodFromFirebase(String query){

    Query searchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Food Name").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\\uf8ff");

    searchQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("Value is: ", value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Context:**

I am using a search query which will return all the items from the database. So ideally, if a user types 'App' it will return Everything which contains 'App' in the Food Name.

So how can I retrieve this data as a List? I do have a model for it but again if someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Edit:

When running this code:

```
Query searchQuery = fitnessTrackerRef.orderByChild("foodName");
```

It will retrieve all the items (as it should), however when I then add the query to be searched, it will return a null value. Here is the code below and two pictures of the results.

```
Query searchQuery = fitnessTrackerRef.orderByChild("foodName").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\\uf8ff");
```

[Without query string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAMag.png)

[With query string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKs1.png)

As shown, it will not return any data when the query is added. Is my searchQuery syntax incorrect?

Comment: Looks like you're running in to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811526/datasnapshot-has-the-object-but-getvalue-will-return-null/44811640#44811640

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Tried the solution and I still get a null key and value. I think it maybe due to the OrderByChild() as it would not be "Food Name" but actually "0" or "1" I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can create a list of food names:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference itemsRef = rootRef.child("items");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String foodName = ds.child("Food Name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(foodName);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
itemsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've just tested using the code above. Now I actually get the key, but the value is still null any idea why?

Comment: Right, so if I edit my code to:  `Query searchQuery = fitnessTrackerRef.orderByChild("foodName")`    It will provide all the entires within the list (as it should) but when I then add `.startAt(query).endAt(query + "\\uf8ff");`  to it, it will then return null any idea why?

Comment: You said you are getting the key and value is still `null` but this is not possible, with the code above you are getting only the value. It returns null when using `.startAt(query).endAt(query + "\\uf8ff")` most likely because you `query` object is not correct. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply (its a side project) haven't solved the issue yet going over it now to see what can be done.

Comment: If there is an error, paste it here to see what's going on.

Comment: What is the value of `query` object that is used as an argument inside the last query?

Comment: That time it was "Apple", now that I think about it, could it be possible that it's not returning anything because it doesn't have a food Name "Apple" I've been assuming it would retrieve everything that contains apple.

Comment: No, it will not. If you'll try to search `Ag` (capital A), will work. You have a food named `Agar`. Firebase doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in objects. Additionally, downloading an entire node to search for fields client-side isn't practical. But that is the maximum that you can get. Try to implemet a third party service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Comment: You can still wait for other answer but if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!